# method not allowed error in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am getting this error when I try to submit a request.

```
Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

And here is my flask code..

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/", methods=['POST','GET'])
def get_form():
  query = request.form["search"]
  print query
```

And my index.html

```
<body>

<div id="wrap">
  <form action="/" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
    <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="How are you feeling?">
     <input id="search_submit" value="Send" type="submit">
  </form>
</div>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
```

Edit.. My complete flask code:

```
from flask import  Flask,request,session,redirect,render_template,url_for
import flask
print flask.__version__
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def entry():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/data", methods=['POST'])
def entry_post():
    query = request.form["search"]
    print query
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Why does the second `/` route handle `GET` **at all** when the first one already handles `GET`? This is confusing Flask no end.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was just experimenting.. on how to get this thing to work.. I tried with just post as well.. but same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are posting to the `entry()` function, while your `entry_post()` function listens to a *different route*; it is registered to only listen to `/data`, not `/`:

```
@app.route("/data", methods=['POST'])
def entry_post():
```

The `/` route doesn't accept `POST`, by default only `GET`, `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` are allowed.

Adjust your form accordingly:

```
<form action="/data" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
```

Take into account that Flask does *not* reload your source unless you [enable debugging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode):

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I did.. now it is just "app.route("/",methods=['POST']) still the same issue

Comment: @Fraz: I cannot actually reproduce your issue. What version of Flask are you using?

Comment: @Fraz: and how are you running the Flask app? Are you certain no older version is still running?

Comment: I just edited the question section with my complete flask code.. I am running simply by python run_flask.py (assuming all the above code is in run_flask.py

Comment: @Fraz: right! There is a crucial difference in that file you didn't include in your question. **The routes differ**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55223/discussion-between-fraz-and-martijn-pieters).