# Flask method not allowed 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm working on a sign in form and am receiving the following message:

```
Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

Reading a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689364/method-not-allowed-flask-error-405) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179593/flask-post-error-405-method-not-allowed) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088054/method-not-allowed-error-in-flask) suggests that the URI of the flask handler should be the same as the one specified in the form's action attribute. I'm trying to submit the form's fields as part of a json object using the ajax API from jquery:

**form.html**

```
<form id="signin_form_id" onsubmit="sign_in()" method="post">
        <label>Email: </label><input id="email0" type="email" name="l_email" required>
        <br>
        <label>Password: </label><input id="password0" type="password" name="l_password" required>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<!-- Body of the index page -->
<body>

    <div class id="main"></div>

    <script>
        <!-- Display index page if session token not set -->
        {% if page_body %}
        if (localStorage.getItem("token") === null) {
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = {{ page_body|safe }}
        }
        {% endif %}
    </script>

  </body>
```

the function **sign_in()** is defined as bellow:

**client.js**

```
function sign_in() {

        var uri, method, formId, jsonObject;

        uri = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/sign_in";
        method = "POST";
        formId = "#signin_form_id";

        // Set-up ajax call
        var request = {
            url: uri,
            type: method,
            contentType: "application/json",
            accepts: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify($(formId).serializeArray())
        };
        // Make the request
        $.ajax(request).done(function(data) { // Handle the response
            if(data.successSignIn === false) {
                // Login failed; display index page
                alert("Login failed!");
                document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = document.getElementById("welcomeview").innerHTML;
            } else {
                // Login succeeded. We load the user's info, messages and also a form in which he can type messages
                // Save the token received from the server. Could also be stored as a cookie
                localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                // Go to the home page
                go_home();
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR) { // Handle failure
                console.log("ajax error upon sign in " + jqXHR.status);
            }
        );
        location.reload();

}
```

The server side code that handle's the request is:

**serverside.py**

```
@app.errorhandler(400)
def page_not_found(e):
    # This page is returned if the request does not contain a json object
    page_body = 'document.getElementById(\"welcomeview\").innerHTML;'
    return render_template('client.html', page_body=page_body)

@app.route('/sign_in', methods=['POST'])
def sign_in_helper():
    json_obj, code = decorator(sign_in, request, check_token=False)
    # Check if the credentials are valid
    if code == 401:
        # Invalid login
        page_body = 'document.getElementById(\"welcomeview\").innerHTML; alert(\"Invalid credentials!\")'
        return render_template('client.html', page_body=page_body)
    else:
        # Return the token, the operation completion flag and the response code
        return json_obj, code

def sign_in(email, password):
    data = query_db('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = ?', [email], one=True)

    if data and check_password_hash(data["password"], password):
        token = token_creator()
        insert_db('UPDATE Users SET token = ? WHERE email = ?', [token, email])
        return jsonify(
            successSignIn=True,
            message="Welcome",
            data=json.dumps({'token': token}),
        ), 200
    return jsonify(
        successSignIn=False,
        message="Username or password invalid"), 401

def decorator(func, request, check_token):
    data = request.get_json(force=True)

    try:
        if check_token:
            token = data.get('token', None)
            if token:
                user = query_db('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE token = ?', [token], one=True)
                if user:
                    json_obj, code = func(**data)
                else:
                    json_obj = jsonify(success=False, message='Invalid token')
                    code = 401
            else:
                json_obj = jsonify(success=False, message='Misformatted data.')
                code = 400
        else:
            json_obj, code = func(**data)
    except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
        json_obj = jsonify(success=False, message='Misformatted data.')
        code = 400
    return json_obj, code
```

If I set the action attribute of the form to **/sign_in** the error is no longer sent, but then there are two submissions of the form data: one from the form and one in the AJAX call.

Why isn't the inner html set accordingly within the jquery call?