# How to use Delete method in python flask

Tags: python, html, flask-sqlalchemy

How to use Delete method in python flask. My code segment has some issues and it shows Method Not Allowed while loading the url http://localhost:8082/api/users/remove_group/5.

```
@app.route('/api/users/remove_group/<int:groupId>',methods=['DELETE'])
def removeGroup(groupId):
try:
    print 'its working--Delete group'
    if userGroup.query.filter_by(group_id=groupId).first() is not None:
        userGroup.query.filter_by(group_id=groupId).delete()
        message='Group removed succesfully\n'
    else:
        print 'Group not found'
        message='Group not found\n'
except HTTPException as error:
    return error(os.version)
return message
```

Comment: Is your html pointing at the right method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088054/method-not-allowed-error-in-flask or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179593/flask-post-error-405-method-not-allowed. BTW why the Java tag?

Comment: Thanks for your effort @doctorlove,  But the link says about get and post methods only.What about Delete method...?

Comment: True, however the error was the same

Comment: Tried `methods=['GET', 'DELETE']` ?

Comment: Already tried with ['GET', 'DELETE'],Thats worked successfully.but when iam using only the  Delete Method  then it shows Method not allowed

Comment: @doctorlove my Html is pointing to the right method.

Comment: Did you REALLY use DELETE method?Show your front end code.

Comment: @hsfzxjy Sorry,i am working with the back end portion,my colleague who is working with the front end is not with me now..

Comment: I can make a methods=['DELETE'] route that works just fine.  You can double check that there isn't a separate problem in your code by setting FLASK_APP to point to your application and running `flask routes`.  That output should include a line that says `removeGroup   DELETE   /api/users/remove_group/<int:groupId>`.  If it doesn't then something else in your code is causing your endpoint to not be registered.  If it does then the problem is likely in the code you are using to call the service.

Answer (score -1):

HTML suports only GET/POST requests in forms, isn't it? Thus, you might try to get access to your `removeGroup` method with `POST` request that is not allowed in `@app.route`.

Please, see also:
[Should PUT and DELETE be used in forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162960/should-put-and-delete-be-used-in-forms)

Comment: Your answer is inrelevant to the question. How can your server handle DELETE requests. It is flask, serverside code. The request doesn't have to be comming from a form.